# Woocommerce: How to change the add to cart text in a certain category?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I already change the add to cart text in global product

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_cart_button_replace', 10);

function add_cart_button_replace() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">+show OFFER</a>');



}
```

but, in a certain product category page like [here](http://www.buy1get2.eu/product-category/free-products/), where I have a *free-products* term in `product-category` custom taxonomy and I want to change the add to cart text into **+choose me** with add to cart link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `has_term` function to check for the desired term.

```
function add_cart_button_replace() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();

    $button_text = __('+show OFFER', 'woocommerce');

   // check if the current product has a "product-category" of "free-products"
    if(has_term('free-products', 'product_cat', $product->get_id()))
        $button_text = __('+choose me', 'woocommerce');

    echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">' . $button_text . '</a>');

}
```

You can also learn more about [`has_term`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function.

**Update**: change `product-category` taxonomy to `product_cat` as per your comment.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but still not working..

Comment: I just update the code you provide
` function add_cart_button_replace() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
$cap = __( '+show OFFER', 'woocommerce' );
echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">' . $cap . '</a>');
   if( has_term( 'free-products', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
    $text = __( '+choose me', 'woocommerce' );    
    echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">' . $text . '</a>');
   }
return $text;
  } `

visit [link](http://www.buy1get2.eu/product-category/free-products/)